# how to calculate crc16 in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, crc

I am using visual c++. I need to calculate crc16 16 bit checksum on packet data.
Their is one getCRC32 function but i did not found any crc16 bit function.

thanks

Comment: Is this question about Visual C++ (a program) or C++ (a language)?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia shows several different variants of crc16 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check do you have a preference?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.algorithm-code.com/wiki/CRC16_Algorithm